# Avoid Activity layout showing before Fragment is created

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have `MainActivity` that starts `DetailsActivity`. `DetailsActivity` layout contains only one `FrameLayout` needed for displaying `DetailsFragment`.

So, when user clicks button from `MainActivity`, `DetailsActivity` is started:

```
public class DetailsActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);
        displayFragment();
    }

    public void displayFragment(){
        Fragment fragment = DetailsFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

The problem is that `DetailsActivity` `onCreate` finishes before `DetailsFragment` `onCreateView`, so user sees blank activity layout for multiple milliseconds. Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: How did you know that `DetailsActivity` finished?

Comment: @MD You misunderstood me, I meant that `DetailsActivity` `onCreate` method finishes earlier that `DetailsFragment` `onCreateView`, so activity layout is shown earlier, than fragment layout is initialized. But in activity layout there only a container for fragment, so user sees blank activity for a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually my mistake. The delay I was talking about was due to I added custom slide animation to fragments transition. In case of activity creation the back stack was empty and it caused small delay before first fragment layout is shown. So I added check:

```
if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() != 0)
```

before calling

```
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.in_transition_left, R.anim.out_transition_left);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible.

In order to show a `Fragment` it must be put into a container. In your case the container (R.id.fragment_container) is part of your main layout (R.layout.activity_info).

Consequentially, in order for R.id.fragment_container to be available to accept the `Fragment`, R.layout.activity_info *MUST* have been inflated prior to calling the following...

```
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
transaction.commit();
```

Unfortunately the act of commiting a `FragmentTransaction` is asynchronous and, most importantly, you've had to call...

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);
```

...before commiting the transaction in order to have a valid reference to the `FrameLayout` (via R.id.fragment_container).

The time it takes for a `Fragment` to become visible is likely to vary based on a number of things (device capabilities, complexity of `Fragment` layout and ancillary code etc). It *MAY* be possible to fiddle the process order but there is no official way of doing it and results would likely be more or less successful on different Android devices.

If you're really worried about the users seeing a blank screen for a short time then all I'd recommend is have the `Activity` create a `ProgressDialog` with a simple "Please wait..." message - create the dialog before commiting the transaction and dismiss it once the `Fragment` has been fully created.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that DetailsActivity onCreate finishes before
>   DetailsFragment onCreateView

That is expected, because from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit()):

> commit() Schedules a commit of this transaction. The commit does not
>   happen immediately; it will be scheduled as work on the main thread to
>   be done the next time that thread is ready

You can try `fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()` soon after the commit.

check [executePendingTransactions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions())

Comment: Thanks for response. I understand, that it is expected, I wondering if there are ways of avoiding it, maybe different design or something. P.S. `fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()` didn't helped.

Comment: @mol Try putting the fragment in the `activity_info.xml` itself instead of dynamically adding it.

Answer (score 0):

According to your problem you have to do like this inside your onCreate:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {

              Fragment fragment = DetailsFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        transaction.commit();

        }
```

And if after doing this, the error is occurring then please show us your fragment java class.

Comment: Thanks for response. I don't see how it can help. The problem is that `DetailsActivity` `onCreate` method finishes earlier that `DetailsFragment` `onCreateView`, so activity layout is shown earlier, than fragment layout is initialized. But in activity layout there only a container for fragment, so user sees blank activity for a moment. It happens only when activity being launched. If I switch fragments after activity already created, there are no delay, because activity layout is already created.